# How can I make system DLLs available during `bazel run`?

Tags: windows, bazel, dependency-management

I have implemented a small Bazel project on CircleCI which uses the MinGW toolchain installed on Windows (via `choco install msys2`).

While running tests with `bazel run --compiler=mingw-gcc //:test_my_lib`, it emits an exit code that seems to indicate missing or corrupt DLLs: `Exited with code exit status 0xc0000139`.

The PATH variable has been set to include `C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin`, where MinGW has the required DLLs required by MinGW (`gtest.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, and `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`).

*How would I properly provide access to DLLs installed at `C:\tools\msys64\mingw64\bin` during bazel runtime?*

---

I have attempted examples of `cc_import` from Bazel documentation. I found a fantastic [Practical Bazel article](https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2021/09/22/practical-bazel-depending-on-a-system-provided-c-cpp-library/) which I used to implement a `mingw_dlls` repo. Then I implemented logic to conditionally add the dlls to `deps` while building on Windows.

Unfortunately, this hasn't changed the exit code. The CI instance does have a second MinGW instance installed at `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin`, but this doesn't appear to be causing issues with a CMake build for this library. I have confirmed that the test executable runs on Windows when copied from the CI instance to another computer.

Thus, I think that I may be misunderstanding how `bazel run` provides access to system DLLs, or that my approach to adding DLL dependencies is incorrect. I have found suggestions to configure MinGW to link these libraries statically, which would not work for other larger projects.

Comment: May be [How to build a windows dll library](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/14380) helps you with your query. Also, you can find dl build file [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/examples/windows/dll/BUILD). Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: @PavanSingh The second link is relevant, but the part I am having trouble with is implementing a `data = select({":is_windows"` from a `new_local_repository` that only exists on windows.

Comment: I was hoping to see an example of how this is solved by other large cross-platform projects -- but most of them solve it by pulling from a remote url instead of the local system. The dlls are downloaded and installed by the mingw-gcc toolchain used on windows by Bazel.